# Windows Phone 8 Getting list of all time zones

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I want to get the list of all time zones that are listed in the Date+Time settings in my windows phone app. How can i do this. Kindly help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't enumerate time zones like you did previously in plain ole c# apps:

```
TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones()
```

You can however, use this NuGet package : https://www.nuget.org/packages/WinRTTimeZones